# How to remove the header of a D3JS tooltip?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

How to remove the header of a D3JS tooltip? I would like to remove the "0" grey header.

[image: tooltip]

Any idea on how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tooltip: {
    format: {
        title: function (d) { return null; }
        // rest of tooltip config here
    }
}
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LBEC7JgwIuAW7LgG8Ep2?p=preview).